# MongoDB slice query into golang

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, slice, mgo

How can i write this below slice query into golang?

```
db.con.find({"repoid":1356485},{"contr":{$slice:[0,10]}}).pretty()
```

Tried with this but not working

```
DB.C("con").Find(bson.M{"id": ID, "contr": bson.M{"$slice": []interface{}{"$contr", offset, limit}}})
```

does not find anything. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question was asked twice yesterday (which questions were already deleted). Asking again and again is not the way to get attention and help.

Comment: Actually, i'm using this platform 1st time for asking question. sorry for my mistake. @icza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Collection.Find()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Find) you can only specify the filter. But what you have is a projection:

```
{"contr":{$slice:[0,10]}
```

Projections can be specified using [`Query.Select()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Query.Select), so this is how you can apply a `$slice` in projection:

```
var results []bson.M // Use your own type here, but this works too

err := DB.C("con").Find(bson.M{"id": ID}).Select(bson.M{
    "contr": bson.M{"$slice": []int{offset, limit}},
}).All(&results)

// handle error
```

Also note sure if the property you filter by is `"id"` or is just a typo and it should be `"_id"`. If the latter, you may also use [`Collection.FindId()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.FindId) to query by document ID:

```
err := DB.C("con").FindId(ID).Select(bson.M{
    "contr": bson.M{"$slice": []int{offset, limit}},
}).All(&results)
```