# Troubles with mongodb ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, objectid

I have Go code that connects to a mongodb database.
The problem is that when I'm trying to get a record from the collection there is an "_id" field of the `ObjectId` type, but in the mgo driver `ObjectId` is

```
type ObjectID [12]byte
```

but when I'm trying to get record Go says:

> reflect.Set: value of type []uint8 is not assignable to type ObjectID

I have tried to create my own `[]uint8` type but I have no idea how to convert `[]uint8` ("ObjectId") to `string` or to find some record by those ids.

```
// ObjectId type that mongodb wants to see
type ObjectID []uint8

// model
type Edge struct {
    ID          ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Name        string   `bson:"name"`
    StartVertex string   `bson:"startVertex"`
    EndVertex   string   `bson:"endVertex"`
}


// method for getting record by those id
session, err := mgo.Dial(config.DatabaseURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error is: %s", err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    //edges collection
    e := session.DB(config.DatabaseName).C(config.EdgesCollection)

    var result models.Edge

    err = e.Find(bson.M{"_id": fmt.Sprintln("ObjectId('", id, "')")}).One(&result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error is: ", err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the "predefined" [`bson.ObjectId`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectId) to model values of MongoDB's ObjectId:

```
type Edge struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Name        string        `bson:"name"`
    StartVertex string        `bson:"startVertex"`
    EndVertex   string        `bson:"endVertex"`
}
```

And when you query an object by ID whose type is MongoDB's ObjectId, use a value of type `bson.ObjectId`. And you may use the [`Collection.FindId()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.FindId) method:

```
var id bson.ObjectId = ...
err = e.FindId(id).One(&result)
```

See details here: [Find by id with mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244024/find-by-id-with-mgo/41244172#41244172); and [MongoDB slice query into golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376454/mongodb-slice-query-into-golang/56378696#56378696)